# Connecting to mysql in docker fails

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm setting up a Dockerfile where I can run my automated tests, and I'm having troubles with connecting to mysql database.

The Dockerfile depends on a prevoously built image and looks like this:

```
# Stage 0, assign argument as multistage image alias
ARG PHP_IMAGE
FROM ${PHP_IMAGE} as image

# Stage 1, start tests
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
  && chmod +x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential \
        git unzip \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        subversion \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli

RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start
RUN mysqladmin -u root -p status

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN npm install -g npm

COPY --from=image /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY scripts/develop.sh develop.sh
COPY scripts/docker-test.sh docker-test.sh

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "bash develop.sh && bash docker-test.sh"]
```

I've added `RUN mysqladmin -u root -p status` to try to debug why connecting to mysql failed and I got

> Enter password: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>   error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
>   Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

To run this I am running

```
docker build -t $TEST_DOCKER_NAME --build-arg PHP_IMAGE=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP -f Dockerfile.test .
```

The `TEST_DOCKER_NAME` and `DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP` are stored in an env file and read from there. The PHP image was built successfuly and I'm using it to copy the files from there to here so that I can run PHPUnit.

When I remove that `RUN` line my build fails when I'm trying to run a script that creates the database

> mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>   error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99 "Cannot assign requested address")'
>   Check that mysqld is running on localhost and that the port is 3306.
>   You can check this by doing 'telnet localhost 3306'

What do I need to do in my Dockerfile to make it work?

Comment: if `status` is password right syntax should be `mysqladmin -u root -pstatus`

Comment: I removed the password and it shows the output of the `mysqladmin` command...

Comment: for future: don't remove passwords, just change it to `****` or `PASSWORD`

Answer (score 3):

### Answer to your specific problem

This is a common mistake people make when using docker. When you use the `RUN` directive in docker you are running a command through to completion, capturing the filesystem changes and then exiting.

So when you have the lines

```
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start
RUN mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

The first one is starting mysql. But then the changes are captured, the container is exited and then a new one is started to run the `mysqladmin` command. Therefore the mysql process is no longer running.

To avoid this you could combine them into a single line like

```
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start && mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

However you will need to do this every time you want to use mysql. Such as in your `develop.sh`.

### Wider answer

It is not recommended to run multiple processes within your container and it is also not recommended to use `init.d` or other system startup frameworks within your container.

You seem to be treating your container like a virtual machine and are having issues because containers are not VMs.

I recommend you explore running mysql in a separate container and then using a tool like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to start and and stop your containers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm missing the point of docker (I'm a noob when it comes to docker). I'm using it this way instead of docker compose, because it's run as a stage in a Jenkins pipeline. I have one dockerfile for php, then one for nginx and now I wanted to do the same to automate running tests on the project. Plus I want to do it myself instead of nagging my devops so that I can learn more :D I'll see how I can fix this issue. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of docker! I would've thought that you could run two containers at the same time as part of your jenkins pipeline so you could urn mysql and php together.

Comment: Actually, that's the part that is confusing me a bit. I'm running this locally on my mac to avoid waiting for every part of Jenkins pipeline to finish (the build takes ~8 minutes), and I thought that all the things from my PHP image (mysql, composer, node, etc) would be available to me when I did the `FROM ${PHP_IMAGE} as image`, but they weren't. Again, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong XD

Comment: Everything in your image will be available. But nothing will be running.

Comment: Yeah, when I add in my stage 1 `FROM image` and then `RUN composer -v` I get error `composer not found` (my files are there from that image which is nice) :D

Comment: Ah I missed that you were using staged builds. You will only have access to resources from the last stage.